# Inconsistent results with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I`m having issues with my code, everytime that I run it I have diferent results, this code should get the name titles from a table and return it to me, all the titles have the same class .Title, but sometimes It only gets 4 titles, 5 titles, 6 titles etc. Every execute returns a different result and I have no ideia what is causing it

```
  let data = [];
  for (const [index, table] of tables.entries()) {
    const item = await table.$$eval(
      ".Title > th > div",
      (el) =>
        el.map((n) =>
          n.textContent
            .trim()
            .replace(/\n/g, "")
            .replace(/\t/g, "")
        )
    );

    data.push(item);
  }

  return data;
};
```

Comment: I need to see preview code to solve this problem

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response, I was traveling, I'm sorry If I misunderstood what you asked (not my first language), do you need to see the results that is returning to me? If it's that, It's exactly like that:
JSON: {
['title-1'],
['title-2'],
['title-3'],

If it stops at title 3,doesn't return any title below it

Comment: If you want to see the code that shows the results, I just console.log the data

Comment: I can definitely help you, whats your skype ? can you screen share ?

Comment: I uploaded my code to aws and now it's working normally, It gets all the titles every time, but now I have another Issue, sometimes it gets the hover title from the table data instead of the the correct value. Example: If the table data is a link  with value 17779 with a hover title "Click here for more information", almost every time gets only the hover title and not the correct value

Comment: Yes, I can screen share

Comment: Ok , Luiz. Lets do that today. My skype is live:.cid.7d7f4d11567fac8d

Comment: Ok, I've added you